# SOLR Filter Query (fq) doesn't work for the strings contain Colon [ : ] or Slash [ / ]?

Tags: regex, filter, solr

In Solr (3.6), i can use `fq` for every fields but not for the fields which contains `Colon [:]` or `Slash [/]` inside, for example, normal `url` fields.

Lets assume some records will be looks like:

```
{
    "title":"Innovation Life and Strategy",
    "url":"http://www.example.com/innovation_life_strategy",
},
{
    "title":"Simple Life",
    "url":"http://www.example.com/simple_life",
},
..
```

I can simply use `fq` for simple fields which **does not contains** `Colon [:]` or `Slash [/]` like "title" here:

```
fq=title:(Strategy)
```

Yes, it returns 1st record.
But then, it returns **not for the `url` field which is having Colons [:] or Slash [/]** inside:

```
fq=url:(life)
```

No, it never returns any of record.

- I don't know why but i think this is because of `Colon [:]`  or `Slash [/]` inside obviously.

How can i?

Comment: whats the analysis performed for both the fields. It seems you are performing text analysis for title and hence the match as tokens would be created. For url as its a single string unless you have analysis to create tokens the filter query would not work. Also you may be better of searching then filtering in this case. Filtering would apply when u want to filter the results on a category and preferably have least analysis on it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to index the url field using LetterTokenizer in your schema.xml. Have a look at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters